# How do I get from $f^2 = \mathrm{id}_V$ to $(f- \mathrm{id}_V)$ and $(f+ \mathrm{id}_V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given 
$f^2= \mathrm{id}_V$,
I'm asked to prove that the direct sum of the kernels of $(f-  \mathrm{id}_V)$ and $(f+ \mathrm{id}_V)$, is the whole space $V$.

Am I correct that since $f\circ f$ is the identity, then $f$ is it's own inverse? I still get lost at how to arrive to the sum and difference expressions though, any hint would do.

(Edited in response to T.Bongers's comment)

Comment: What problem are you solving, exactly? In general, just knowing that $f^2 = \operatorname{id}_V$ is not enough to get the kernel of $f - \operatorname{id}_V$. But writing the direct sum decomposition does not require knowing the actual kernels.

Comment: @T.Bongers Oh yeah, I overlooked the problem. I'm not asked to get the actual kernels. Just prove that their direct sum is the whole space $V$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $f^2-\operatorname{id}_V=(f-\operatorname{id}_V)(f+\operatorname{id}_V)=0\quad(*)$

Now since the polynomial $(x-1)$ and $(x+1)$ are coprime then by Bezout's identity there are $S,T$ two polynomials such that
$$S(x)(x-1)+T(x)(x+1)=1$$
so applying to $f$ and then to $x\in V$ and using $(*)$ we get 
$$\underbrace{S(f)(f-\operatorname{id}_V)(x)}_{\in\ker(f+\operatorname{id}_V)}+\underbrace{T(f)(f+\operatorname{id}_V(x))}_{\in\ker(f-\operatorname{id}_V)}=\operatorname{id}_V(x)=x$$
so $$V=\ker(f-\operatorname{id}_V)+\ker(f+\operatorname{id}_V)$$
and since the intersection is trivially $\{0\}$ we get the desired result.

Comment: This is very much ok! I am suggesting the same actually. But with constant polynomials $S(x)=-1/2$ and $T(x)=1/2$ :-)

Comment: I intentionally gave this proof since it is valid in a more general case.

Comment: Hi. At one point I arrived at the product $(f-\mathrm{id}_V)(f+\mathrm{id}_V)$, but couldn't quite justify the polynomial structure of function composition. So I scrapped that line of thinking

Comment: @acidiclemon $(f-\operatorname{id}_V)  (f+\operatorname{id}_V) =  f^2 + f \operatorname{id}_V - \operatorname{id}_V f - \operatorname{id}_V^2$. Using $\operatorname{id}_V f = f = f \operatorname{id}_V $ and $\operatorname{id}_V^2 = \operatorname{id}_V$ yields the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x\in V$ is arbitrary, what can you say about the vectors
$$
x_1=\frac{x+f(x)}2\qquad\text{and}\qquad x_2=\frac{x-f(x)}2.
$$

Comment: Strong deja vu -vibe. Fairly sure I have used this trick earlier :-(

Comment: Assuming that the characteristic of the base field is $\neq2$. Otherwise the claim is probably false.

Comment: @JL it is false: take the transpose operator